# MS Access "?" character in Datasheet View

Tags: database, ms-access

I am using ms access 2010.

I have a view (C) created by joining two other views (A,B).

Column X (`LONGTEXT`) from view A is properly displayed in View A but in View C a strange character appears instead of the value.

View C has a GROUP BY clause by Column X

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Any ideas what causes this ?

Thanks

If I remove the `GROUP BY` section everything is ok.
I do not understand why this problem appears when using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Grouping by a Memo field means you have a design error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a limitation with Memo fields in Access that prevented the field from being included in a group by clause. My guess is that since LongText is essentially Memo that the same limitation applies.

Comment: I assume the limitation regarded the truncation of the memo field, but in this case my value is not truncated. Thanks for the tip ... I will do some more research on this limitations